# Does TLP dynamically change according to power source?

Tags: power-management, battery

I know that TLP automatically starts when the system boots up, but I wonder if it dynamically changes according power source. For example, when I manually type sudo tlp start when I'm running my laptop on battery power it responds with a "TLP started in battery mode." and when I plug in the charger it says "TLP started in AC mode."

Is TLP able to do that on its own or do I have to manually change it each time I change power source?

Comment: are you sure that is starts automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does
You can check it yourself by running  `sudo tlp stat` once on battery & once on AC power.

Comment: No. It does not by default.  It needs to be configured to do this.  This answer should be taken down since it does not include how to configure TLP inorder to actually switch the CPU to power save on Battery state and toggle Balanced on AC.